# google ad inside grid

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need to make a uniform grid using html/css (and possibly javascript) consisting of 5 columns and n number of rows. Most of the grid will be taken up by uniform thumbnail images. However, on the second row I would like to place a google adsense ad that takes up 5 columns and 2 rows. Here is an image of what it [should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW681.png). (Sorry not enough reputation to post the image directly.)

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: list-item;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li class="bigger-thing"><!--- ad here --></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/187/133" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can I do this with pure css? If so how? If not how would you do it with javascript?